# Pushing to 2D Array

Tags: ruby, arrays, iteration

I'm trying to push an array of names into a 2D array. When the 2D array hits 4 entries, add to the next position of the array. For example:

```
groups[0]
[
    [0] "bobby",
    [1] "tommy",
    [2] "johnny",
    [3] "brian"
]

groups[1]
    [0] "christina",
    [1] "alex",
    [2] "larry",
    [3] "john"
]
```

Here's how I'm trying to do it, and it's not working. I realize there is probably some built in ruby functions that will do this process automatically, but I want to write it out manually first:

```
def make_group(the_cohort)
  y=0
  x=1
  groups=[]

  the_cohort.each do |student|
      groups[y].push student
      x+=1
      y+=1 && x=1 if x==4
  end
end
```

Thanks in advance. Using ruby 2.1.1p73

Comment: That's not a 2D array, Ruby doesn't have those (unless you count `Matrix`). That's just an array of arrays.

Comment: Enumerable#each_slice, mentioned by @ChrisHeald, was made specifically for this task, but there are other ways to do it. Here's one: `(0...arr.size).step(4).map { |i| arr[i,4] }`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your algorithm can be expressed as:

```
1. If the last array in groups has 4 entries, add another array to groups
2. Push the entry into the last array in groups
```

In code:

```
groups = [[]]
the_cohort.each do |student|
   groups.push [] if groups.last.length == 4
   groups.last.push student
end
```

For each student, it'll look at the last entry in `groups` (which is the only one which could possibly not be full), decide if it needs to add a new sub-array to `groups`, and then push the student into last sub-array.

That said, it sounds like what you really want is to take a list of names and split them into groups of four. Ruby has this built in already via `each_slice`:

```
the_cohort = %w(bobby tommy johnny brian christina alex larry john)
the_cohort.each_slice(4).to_a
# => [["bobby", "tommy", "johnny", "brian"], ["christina", "alex", "larry", "john"]]
```

Comment: Thank you, groups = [[]] is exactly what I needed to do as the list of lists was null and you can't push to it.

I knew about each_slice but wanted to solve the problem 'manually' per se before using a built in function. Appreciate you taking the time to explain both!